# Angular 7 SSR use navigator to define parameters

Tags: angular, angular-universal, angular-seo

I have an angular 7 universal app in two languages, Spanish and English. I want to display the site in the user's configured language. In order to achieve that I have the following setup.

First my `app.component.html` which only has a router-outlet like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

in my `app-routing.module.ts` I have the following configuration:

```
{
        path: 'es',
        data: { lang: 'es' },
        component: LanguageComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
            },
            {
                path: '**',
                redirectTo: 'pagina-no-encontrada'
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        path: 'en',
        data: { lang: 'en' },
        component: LanguageComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule),
            },
            {
                path: '**',
                redirectTo: 'page-not-found'
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: LanguageComponent,
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/es/pagina-no-encontrada',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
```

I do it that way to let the `LanguageComponent` detect the user language and redirect to the relevant `/es` or `/en`.

My `language.component.ts` has the following logic:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Inject, PLATFORM_ID, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Data, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateService } from '../services/translate.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';
import { LANG_EN_NAME } from '../translate/lang-en';
import { LANG_ES_NAME } from '../translate/lang-es';
import { isPlatformBrowser, DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-language',
    templateUrl: 'language.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['language.component.scss']
})
export class LanguageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subscription: Subscription;
    private isPlatformBrowser: boolean;

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
                private translate: TranslateService,
                private router: Router,
                @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.isPlatformBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
        this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((d: Data) => {
            if (d['lang'] !== undefined) {
                this.translate.use(d['lang']);
            } else if (this.isPlatformBrowser && navigator) {
                const userLanguage = navigator.language;
                if (userLanguage) {
                    if (userLanguage.startsWith('en')) {
                        this.router.navigateByUrl(LANG_EN_NAME);
                    } else {
                        this.router.navigateByUrl(LANG_ES_NAME);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                this.router.navigateByUrl(LANG_ES_NAME);
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.subscription) {
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

so I can successfully detect the language via the navigator and display the page by going to the relevant section. On each component such as the `HomeComponent` within the HomeModule I invoke a `SeoService` which sets the title, the meta-description and sets the HTML lang tag depending on the language is set.

The problem I have is very weird as it comes to the google search results. Sometimes I get the site having the title displayed in Spanish then the description in english, some other times all English...and all started to happen since I decided to start using the navigator as driver of the language detection.

First I don't know whether my approach is the best to take in this scenario and in case it is, have you come across this problem of google engine language issues?

**UPDATE:** 
I think my question goes more towards the fact that in order to perform SSR I need to know the language of the browser of the user. Is it possible to somehow "transfer" that value to the server to perform that rendering? Otherwise I honestly don't know how to know the "user settings" to perform the actual rendering of the page and be "google friendly" if that makes sense

Comment: Do you have the correct `lang` attribute setup on your page?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. As for the correct routing, navigation and translation, yes all is fine as it’s well tested and it’s functioning. The trouble seems to be between the routing and SSR using the language to render the site when the Google not crawls the page

Comment: Yeah but you need to add the `lang`  attribute to your pages so that google does not get confused: `<html lang='es'>` or `<html lang='en'>`

Comment: Yeah it’s also set